# Issues with linking and images in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/UQpeJ/)
(Note that the result will not display properly without the images referenced)

I'm a student worker at a University with some programming experience. My boss wants me to make a slideshow similar to the one that can be seen [here.](https://sakai.rutgers.edu/portal) I don't know anything about Javascript or jQuery other than the basic W3 schools tutorials so I decided to get code from outside sources to modify for my own purposes.

Two issues have arisen with this build of the code.
My first problem is the simpler of the two.

```
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(<img src="img\rssSmall.jpg" />)"></a>
```

I'm trying to make little thumbnail images at the bottom of the slideshow to tab between slides. Unfortunately due to nested quotes the IDE (Aptana if it matters) interprets the coded quotes as

```
"$('.slideshow').blinds_change(<img src="
```

and

```
" />)"
```

Thus it displays " />)" instead of the proper thumbnail image.

My second problem is making each slide into a link. For some reason a simple  tag doesn't work.

```
<li><a href="http:\\google.com"><img class="slide" src="img\sakaiupgrade.png" alt="Whats new in Sakai?" /></a></li>
```

I assume this has more to do with the Javascript/jQuery side of things, which is way above my head at the moment.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

If you want to throw in some images yourself the size is w500 h350 for the slides and w77 h54 for the tabs. Or I could try uploading all the relevant images if need be.

Comment: <img src="img\rssSmall.jpg" /> should be in single quotes in your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to the head of your page, underneath the `<script` tags.

This will start off the blinds process.

```
<script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".slidehsow").blinds();
    });


</script>
```

Next, you `<a` links are find, however if you'd like to add a thumbnail change them to:

```
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(0)"><img src="img/somethingThumbnail.jpg" alt="Link to Slide 1" /></a>
```

And as they, job's a carrot!

So you main images are contained within the `<li>` elements and the thumbnails are within the `<a` elements.

---

***Edit for Question 2***

Looking through the jQuery blinds code, there's no means for it to translate the `<li>` items into proper links - as the images are changed to a background image of a new div.

You'll need to edit the `jquery.blinds-0.9.js` file, like so:

Line 49 becomes:

```
blinds_images[blinds_images.length] = { 'title': e.alt, 'src': e.src, 'href': $(this).parent().attr("href") }
```

This add the parent elements (the the image) `href` attribute to the array.

Line 89 becomes:

```
,'cursor': 'pointer'
```

This means the mouse will become link a link pointer when over the image

Insert this line into line 91:

```
tile.click(function (e) { window.location = blinds_images[0]['href']; });
```

This set's up the default link from the first tile.

Finally, line 115 (or 114 before inserted line) becomes:

```
$(this).find('.tile_' + i + '_' + j).show().css('background', 'transparent ' + 'url("' + config.images[config.img_index]['src'] + '") -' + (i * config.tiles_width) + 'px -' + (j * config.tiles_height) + 'px no-repeat').click(function (e) { window.location = config.images[config.img_index]['href']; });
```

Again, this picks up the `href` and directs the browser there when clicked for a particular slide.

With these changes, you're usual code of `<li><a href="somelink.htm"><img src="someIMage.png" /></a></li>` will work as expected.

***CAVEAT*** I've not tested this *without* the `<a` elements, so the list items without links will either need an empty one (maybe) or the jQuery code will need to be tweaked further to capture any `null` values.

Comment: .blinds_change seems to just take an index value.

`<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$(.slideshow').blinds_change(0)">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$(.slideshow').blinds_change(1)">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$(.slideshow').blinds_change(2)">3</a>
  <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$(.slideshow').blinds_change(3)">4</a>
  <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$(.slideshow').blinds_change(4)">5</a>
  <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$(.slideshow').blinds_change(5)">6</a>`

This is how the original author wrote the code.

Comment: Does that work with the index value? As then you've no quotes worry about.

Comment: Yes, that code works. But I need to modify it in a way that includes an image.

Comment: If I change the `<a>` tag to `<a href="img\rssSmall.jpg" class="change_link"></a>` when I click on a tab it takes me to a different page which is just the tab image. The tab image does not display in the tab.

Comment: You need the jQuery code to go with it to prevent the href from firing, and the jQuery to use that instead.

Comment: With the new edit you can revert the jQuery changes I'd suggested, and stick with the demo code. However the earlier code is a little tidier and more the way to go (I think).

Comment: That last edit works wonderfully for the thumbnails! Thank you so much! Despite the change do the URL you mentioned originally, the slide doesn't seem to want to go anywhere when clicked on. One would think it would be a simple matter of putting an `<a>` tag around the image, but apparently not.


Here's what it looks like right now

`<li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="img\sakaiupgrade.png" alt="Whats new in Sakai?" /></a></li>`

Just to make sure I haven't done anything idiotic.

Comment: That `a` look fine to me, unless the blinds code is somehow stripping it... I can't seem to replicate the problem with the fiddle.

Comment: Trying in Fiddle takes you to Google? Hmmm...
Well I'll post another comment if I can figure out anything.

Comment: To be more specific: Does the larger Sakai Upgrade image link to Google for you? That's what isn't working for me right now.

Comment: Looking at the blinds code, the default functionality has no mechanisim for carrying over hrefs - above I've shown what you'll need to edit should you wish to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

To your first issue:

You can escape your quotes using a slash, e.g.

```
"$('.slideshow').blinds_change('<img src=\"/some/path\" />')"
```

To your second issue:

Your link is incorrect. It should be:

```
href="http://google.com"
```